# jQuery not working on overlay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a weird issue that I've never experienced before. I have jQuery loaded correctly, but I can't seem to get it to do anything.

I'm trying to use jQuery to quickly fade in a series of text elements on my sites initial wrapper. My JavaScript is functioning expected on the main page, so I'm thinking it's an issue with my CSS?

Code sample:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="effects.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
```

The overlay in question...

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="overlay">
  <h1 id="overlaytext1">Fade this in</h1>
  <h1 id="overlaytext2">Then this</h1>
  <h1 id="overlaytext3">then this</h1>
  <h1 id="overlaytext4">then this.</h1>
  <div id="overlaycontent">
   <h1>Compelling paragraph.</h1>
   <h1 id="overlaytext">Credit</h1>
  </div>
 </div>
<-- Main Page Content -->
</div>
</body>
```

My CSS

```
#overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.90);
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:1;
}

#overlaycontent {
    padding-top: 20%;
    width: 50%;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 26px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}

#overlaytext {
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 22px;
}

#overlaytext1 {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.20);
    font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-top: 5%;
}

#overlaytext2 {
    position: fixed;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.20);
    font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
    font-size: 40px;
    right: 5%;
    bottom: 5%;
}

#overlaytext3 {
    position: fixed;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.20);
    font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-left: 1%;
}

#overlaytext4 {
    position: fixed;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.20);
    font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
    font-size: 40px;
    right: 1%;
    bottom: 15%;
}
```

Contents of effects.js

```
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#overlaytext1').show();
  }, 1000);
}};
```

To me, everything looks okay. The only thing I can think of is something with the z-index or position causing a problem?

Any thoughts?

Comment: how can we get effect and main.js?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fiddle with css class to hide your overlay text and javascript to show it 1 second after each other: https://jsfiddle.net/stevenng/0n52dajm/1/

CSS:

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}

#overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.90);
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:1;
}

#overlaycontent {
    padding-top: 20%;
    width: 50%;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 26px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}

#overlaytext {
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 22px;
}

#overlaytext1 {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.20);
    font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-top: 5%;
}

#overlaytext2 {
    position: fixed;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.20);
    font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
    font-size: 40px;
    right: 5%;
    bottom: 5%;
}

#overlaytext3 {
    position: fixed;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.20);
    font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-left: 1%;
}

#overlaytext4 {
    position: fixed;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.20);
    font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
    font-size: 40px;
    right: 1%;
    bottom: 15%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="overlay">
  <h1 id="overlaytext1" class="hide">Fade this in</h1>
  <h1 id="overlaytext2" class="hide">Then this</h1>
  <h1 id="overlaytext3" class="hide">then this</h1>
  <h1 id="overlaytext4" class="hide">then this.</h1>
  <div id="overlaycontent">
   <h1>Compelling paragraph.</h1>
   <h1 id="overlaytext">Credit</h1>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ $('#overlaytext1').fadeIn('slow'); }, 1000);
  setTimeout(function(){ $('#overlaytext2').fadeIn('slow'); }, 2000);
  setTimeout(function(){ $('#overlaytext3').fadeIn('slow'); }, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work.  Few comments.  You're missing an '!' at:

```
 </div>
<-- Main Page Content -->
</div>
```

You also need to specify the correct syntax for the setTimeout function:

```
var timeOut = window.setTimeout(function() {
    $('#overlaytext1').show();
}, 1000);
```

or:

```
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#overlaytext1').show();
  }, 1000);
});
```

(You were missing the parenthesis - you had a brace)

Working fiddle at: https://jsfiddle.net/dhqdt3vk/